# Access params hash from other action in same controller wihtout reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def newpass
    @somevariable = {
                         "a-var" => params[:token_id],
                         "b-var" => params[:client_id],
                         "c-var" => params[:user_id]}
end
def setpass
    #I need to access this hash values without params getting reset
end
```

end

I have an action newpass with a corresponding view which calls setpass. I access URL's params in newpass action. I want to use these param values in setpass but the values get reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using a link:

You need to send those values when your request hits `setpass` action in `UsersController`. You can create a button, or a `link_to` to send along those `params` values. Here is how:

```
<%= link_to "Go to", setpass_path(token_id: params[:token_id]) %>
```

You can pass `params` in `_path` method, and you will receive all those values inside the respective method in controller.

## Using a form:

If you are using a form, and you would like to send those values along, `hidden_field_tag` is the best option here. You can do something like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :token_id, params[:token_id] # this line must exist inside your form element %>
```

Comment: I am actually submitting a form to setpass action as form_tag("setpass", method: "patch", 'data-type' => 'application/json'). How should I do that here?